# Can't boot into Windows on Surface Book after live booting Kali Linux

Tags: linux, boot

I may have messed up my computer. So I tried live booting Kali Linux. To do that I opened up the Surface UEFI and disabled secure boot.

I also rearranged the boot device order to Windows Boot Manager, USB Storage, Internal Storage, and last PXE Network.

Then I booted into Kali. I chose the Live System option. An error occurred when I clicked the padlock button so I restarted my computer, and then tried the installer button. I got up to the point when it said I couldn't partition my USB drive, probably because it didn't have enough space. So I powered off my computer and took out the USB. Then I booted into Bitlocker Recovery. I clicked skip and then pressed the option to restart and use Windows 10. Normally, it would bring me to Windows 10, but instead it brings me back to Bitlocker Recovery.

I tried undoing some of the changes I made, but to no avail. Is there a way to fix this? I also tried to open BIOS settings and reset to default settings, but I can't seem to open BIOS settings and only the Surface UEFI.

Edit: I also reenabled Secure Boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried undoing some of the changes I made but to no avail. Is there a way to fix this? I also tried to open BIOS settings and reset to default settings, but I can't seem to open BIOS settings and only the Surface UEFI.

The only way to boot into Windows is to provide the BitLocker recovery key.  **If you do not have the recovery key then you will be unable to boot into Windows.**  This is due to the fact, you made a configuration change, with BitLocker protection enabled.

In the future, you will want to suspend and/or disable BitLocker before you make configuration changes to avoid the need to input the BitLocker recovery key.

Due to the nature of the state your device is in, the only other solution to this problem is to completely reinstall Windows. Since BitLocker is a full disk encryption solution this would mean all data on the device will be lost.